# Why SCK, MOSI and MISO pins are always hang on high level when connect to orange pi zero?

Tags: python, hardware, spi, orange-pi

I am working on orange pi zero with armbian os. I want to communicate between pi and si4463 through SPI, I've used spidev python lib to write/read data. Unfortunately, my spi on pi didn't work yet because of the 3 wires SPI (SCK, MOSI, and MISO) always pull high when the bus was idle cause appearing a weird signal before my CS pin de-active each transaction. I run some tests to find out the problem

1. Remove si4463 out of pi -> 3 wires SPI was pulled low, look good for my target.
2. Using another master that connects to si4463 instead using the pi -> 3 wires SPI was pulled low and I could control the slave correctly.

Python

```
import spidev

self.__spi = spidev.SpiDev()
self.__spi.open(1, 0)
# Setting spi
self.__spi.max_speed_hz = self.__speed
self.__spi.mode = 0 # [CPOL|CPHA] <-> 0b00

self.__spi.xfer2([0x44])
c = self.__spi.readbytes(1)
```

[image]

Data viewer si4463 with pi

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If nothing is active on the bus, you might get an undefined state on the line. Check if the "weird signal" still appears with a pull-down resistor.

Comment: Thanks, I will try putting some resistors which was be pulled to low level on the data line

Comment: That's work when pull all data line to low. Thank a lot!